# Does Spring roo use jspx as view technology

Tags: java, jsp, velocity, spring-roo

I have seen that view files used in spring roo are JSPX files.
Is it possible to use JSP or velocity for view?

What's the best way to change JSPX to velocity?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, in theory it would be possible to support other views such as JSP or velocity, since everything in Roo is modular and every feature is an addon. However, afaik, no such support has been implemented yet to date.